# В чём разница между %~dp0 и %~dpn0

Tags: cmd, bat

Пыталась найти в интернете и понять в чём разница между этими двумя командами. Вдруг здесь есть знатоки, кто может помочь уловить эту тонкую грань. В интернете нашла следующие определения:

`%~dpn0`  - возвращает диск, путь и имя текущего сценария.

`%~dp0`  - полный путь (включая завершающий слэш) к каталогу выполняемого скрипта.

Но так и не поняла в каких случаях лучше всего использовать какую команду

Comment: Применение модификаторов переменной зависит от задачи, которую Вы хотите решить. Например, в каталоге скрипта могут оказаться вспомогательные или обрабатываемые скриптом файлы. Тогда нужно получить каталог: **%~dp0**. Иногда необходимо найти процесс, который запустил скрипт (если запущено несколько с разными именами) - ищем имя скрипта (без расширения): **%~dp0**. Короче говоря, задач может оказаться великое множество, поэтому вариантов применения модификаторов существует большое количество. Уточните, пожалуйста,  Ваш вопрос: какую задачу хотите решить, как её решаете, где возник "затык"?

Answer (score 1):

Путь, например «C:\Users\User\Desktop\name.cmd», можно разбить так:

- `%~d` — C:
- `%~p` — \Users\User\Desktop\
- `%~n` — name
- `%~x` — .cmd

`%~dpn0` будет «C:\Users\User\Desktop\name», тогда как `%~dp0` будет «C:\Users\User\Desktop\»
Применение у всех разное. Второе может пригодиться для получения пути, где содержится выполняющийся скрипт, а первое для изменения расширения скрипта.
Нередко используют n и x вместе, то есть `%~nx0`.

Answer (score 1):

Разница в том, что

- в случае `%dpn0` вы получите **тоже имя** (например `c:\Program Files\desktop`),
- а в случае `%dp0` - нет (только `c:\Program Files\`).

(Файл в папке  `c:\Program Files` называется `desktop.ini`.)

---

*Объяснение:*

Значение отдельных символов:

`%` - обязательно
`~` - без кавычек
`d` - drive (диск)
`p` - path (путь)
`n` - name (имя)
`0` - позиция, обычно в виде переменной, я буду использовать переменную `i`.

---

*Демонстрация:*

Я буду постепенно строить ваше выражение `%~dpni`.

Здесь моя текущая папка:

```
>cd
C:\Program Files\VstPlugins
```

В ней находится файл `read me.txt`. Начинаем:

```
>for %i in ("read me.txt") do @echo %i
"read me.txt"

>for %i in ("read me.txt") do @echo %~i
read me.txt

>for %i in ("read me.txt") do @echo %~di
C:

>for %i in ("read me.txt") do @echo %~dpi
C:\Program Files\VstPlugins\

>for %i in ("read me.txt") do @echo %~dpni
C:\Program Files\VstPlugins\Read me
```

Answer (score 0):

Я это понимаю так:
есно.%~dp0>abc.txt ---> Батник, в котором есть эта строка, в abc.txt файл запишит адрес папки, с левым слешем на конце, где находится этот батник.
есно.%~dpn0>abc.txt ---> Всё тоже самое что и в первом случае, только сразу за слешем ещё допишит имя батника без его расширения.

В обоих случаях адреса будут записана без обрамления двойными кавычками.